# OpenSSL EVP_aes_128_cbc decryption got unexpected result

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I encrypted a string with EVP_aes_128_cbc cipher, then changed the 1st byte of the ciphertext, and decrypt this changed ciphertext. Unexpectly, it didn't decrypt error or get a fully wrong result, but got a wrong 1st 16 bytes and same string of rest. Here is the encrypt func:

```
    int do_crypt1(unsigned char *in, unsigned char *outbuf, int inlen, int do_encrypt)
 {
     unsigned char inbuf[1024];
     int outlen;
     EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

     /*
      * Bogus key and IV: we'd normally set these from
      * another source.
      */
     unsigned char key[32] = "test";
     unsigned char iv[] = "1234567812345678";

     /* Don't set key or IV right away; we want to check lengths */
     ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
     EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL,
                       do_encrypt);
     OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(ctx) == 16);
     OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(ctx) == 16);

     /* Now we can set key and IV */
     EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, do_encrypt);
     int update_len = 0;

     for (;;) {
         memcpy(inbuf, in, inlen);
         if (inlen <= 0)
             break;
         
         if (!EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen)) {
             /* Error */
             EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
             return 0;
         }
         update_len += outlen;
         if(inlen <= 1024)
            break;
        
     }
     if (!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf+outlen, &outlen)) {
         /* Error */
         EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
         return 0;
     }

     EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    update_len += outlen;

     return update_len;
 }
```

and in the main:

```
    unsigned char* b = (unsigned char*)malloc(1024);
    unsigned char* hmac_code = (unsigned char*)malloc(1024);

    int len = do_crypt1(value, hmac_code, strlen(value), AES_ENCRYPT);
    printf("%s\n", value);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%x", *(hmac_code + i));
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n", len);
    // printf("%s\n", hmac_code);
    *hmac_code = 0x23;
    len = do_crypt1(hmac_code, b, len, AES_DECRYPT);
    printf("%d\n", len);
    printf("%s\n", b);

    free(hmac_code);
    free(b);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/powH3.png)

Could anyone give me the reason and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually as long as your plaintext is at least 17 bytes, the first *17* decrypted bytes should be wrong -- but since you're displaying the invalid decryption as text, some of the bytes may be invisible: in your example, the output is 2 chars shorter, so clearly 2 chars of the first 17 aren't visible. That's the expected result for damage in (at the beginning of) the first block of a 2-block (or more) CBC ciphertext for a 16-byte-block cipher like AES; see the diagram in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)) to understand why.

If you want detection of damage to the ciphertext, don't use CBC mode, or at least don't use it alone. Common/standard solutions nowadays are:

- add authentication, such as HMAC. (Intriguingly your code already uses the variable name `hmac_code` even though you don't do anything even remotely related to HMAC.)
- use an authenticated-encryption mode, like GCM, which effectively combines encryption and (some type of) MAC internally. Most authenticated modes today, including GCM, also support 'additional' or 'associated' data that is authenticated but not encrypted, and as a result are called [AEAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Authenticated_encryption_with_associated_data_(AEAD)), but you may or may not care about that.
- use an error-propagating mode. These were popular decades ago, around the time of presidents Nixon, Ford, Carter, and Reagan, but are now mostly considered obsolete and are not directly supported by OpenSSL.

Also, BTW, your code is completely pants for values longer than 1024 bytes, which your test clearly doesn't exercise. First of all you don't need to break up such a value into chunks at all, but if for some reason you want to, the method you implemented is wrong.

Plus, the IV for CBC should be different *and* unpredictable every time; using a hardcoded value like this exposes you to two different classes of attacks. In general the advice you will get on Stacks actually related to security is 'don't roll you own'. Cryptographic code written by people who don't know what they're doing, even if/when it produces the correct output, is usually insecure. This is the major difference between crypto/security software and others; you can easily see if your editor or spreadsheet or database produces correct or incorrect output, and as long as the output is correct that's usually all you need, but you can't tell by looking at the output from an encryption/decryption program whether it is secure or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually this is a simple test for OpenSSL encrypt lib, also I did the HMAC test and more, so the variable name may be not clear to understand. The wrong logic of method and the iv are for the same reason.

Comment: What I cannot understand is for the CBC mode, the decryption use the previous block ciphertext to decrypt next block, when the 1st block was tampered, why the rest of blocks can be decrypted succuessfully and correctly? BTW, now I implemented the method by using ECB mode to encrypt the plaintext, which is added a crc32 value of the string at the end. Does this way work effectively and safely?

Comment: If (any of) the first ciphertext block is changed, the first block of plaintext is (all) garbage. The second ciphertext block is NOT changed and is decrypted correctly _except_ that the plaintext is effectively XORed with the change in the first ciphertext block, which in your test is only its first byte. The third block is unchanged and so is the second so it decrypts correctly. This should all be apparent when you look at the diagram. CRC is not a MAC; an attacker who changes the ciphertext can easily fake the CRC. And in nearly all cases ECB allows more attacks. My point stands.

Comment: Got it! Now I know what CBC does. For the point of ECB and CRC, my work concerns about system performance optimization more than the best security, so this may be not a bad way relatively，not sure.